Modified duration with zero-coupon bond yields
I want to calculate the modified duration for a series of non-fixed cashflows (monthly). I have a series of monthly discount factors.
To do this I have been calculating the Macauley duration as follows:
$$
 \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} t_{i}\,  PV_{i}}{V}
$$
Where, V is total PV and PV_i is the PV of a cashflow at time i calculated using the relevant discount factor.
I understand that this is actually the Fisher–Weil duration. This is slightly different to the Macauley duration that I would get if I were to calculate a yield to maturity and then use that to calculate my PV_i terms in the above equation (which I believe is the mathematically correct approach if I am then going to calculate a modified duration using it).
I have then been dividing the Macauley duration above through by a yield to maturity to get a modified duration. Which I am using as an approximation to interest rate sensitivity (i.e. the impact of a 1bp increase in spot rates across my yield curve).
My question is what is the correct way to calculate a modified duration when using discount factors instead of a yield to maturity? Is it to calculate a yield to maturity -> use this to then calculate revised discount factors -> use these to calculate the Macauley duration and then divide through by yield to maturity? Is using the Fisher-Weil duration as I have been doing inappropriate?

imho what you have been doing is good and fisher-weil (as long as you have the discount factors or forward rates available, which not everyone does) is in fact preferable to the traditional duration for assessing interest rate risk.
